# How to get the x-coordinate of bars in barplot

Tags: r, plot, label, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a barplot combined with line plots, but I have troubles centering all graphs, so it match the x-axis. I want the bar labels (had to censor them ;) ) and points of both line plots centered with the x-axis ticks.

I don't really get why the x-axis ticks are correctly centered with bars, but everything else is dis-centered in such strange way (although I'm using the same variable x to position both of them).

How can I center them all together.

Here is the code that I have made for plotting (the image it produces is below):

```
#### base sytem
par(mar = rep(4, 4))
barData <- con
y <- lineData <- CPL
z <- CPLmax
x <- barplot(barData, 
             axes = FALSE,
             col = "green", 
             xlab = "",
             ylab = "",
             ylim = c(0, max(con) * 1.1))
axis(1, at = x, labels = timeline)
axis(4, at = NULL)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x = x, y = y, type = "b", col = "blue", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", ylim = c(0, max(CPL) * 1.1))
lines(x = x, y = z, type = "b", col = "red",  axes = FALSE, ylab = "", ylim = c(0, max(CPL) * 1.1))
axis(2, at = NULL)
text(x = x, y = 3, labels = barData, pos = 1 )
abline(v= x, col="purple")
print(x)
print(y)
box()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to @JTT's answer - you could fix the xlim params like this:

```
con <- setNames(runif(12), seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), "month"))
xlim <- c(0, length(con)*1.25)
x <- barplot(con, col = "green", xlab = "", ylab = "", ylim = c(0, max(con) * 1.1), axes = FALSE, xlim = xlim)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x = x, type = "b", y = runif(12), xlim = xlim, xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = FALSE)
abline(v = x, col = "red")
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the coordinate system of the plot when you call `par(new=TRUE)`. This misaligns the new added elements when drawn over the existing barplot. Omit the `par()`, and instead of `plot()` just after that, use `lines()` as you do on the next line.

As an example, instead of this:

```
d<-1:10
x<-barplot(d)
y<-d+rnorm(10)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x, y, type="b")
```

rather do this:

```
d<-1:10
x<-barplot(d)
y<-d+rnorm(10)
lines(x, y, type="b")
```

Or, if different axes for different elements on the plot are needed, you might consider setting the x-axis range explicitly, e.g.:

```
d<-1:10
x<-barplot(d, xlim=c(0,12))
y<-d+rnorm(10)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x, y, type="b", xlim=c(0,12))
```

Comment: Ok. I see that this does align everything to the x-axis ticks and this is mayor progress. However the problem is that I need to have the line plots in different scale than the barplot (equivalent of Excel's second axis). That is why I use par(new=TRUE). Is there anything I can do to preserve the correct x-coordinates of barplot?

Comment: I edited the answer a bit to give an example of this.